# How to resolve filepath in ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I spent my whole day googling it and asking on various platforms . I can not find a way to simply choose and upload file in ionic app (pdf,rtf etc).

In `cordovaFileTransfer.upload` function I need to provide filepath. I tried `document.getElementById('file').value`  (gives fakepath) etc but to no success. My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021110/how-to-get-path-of-selected-file-in-angularjs) went unanswered therefore I need to ask again.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.upload = function(){
    document.getElementById('fileu').click();
$scope.fileNameChanged = function(filoename) {
  console.log(filoename.files);
    
}}})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="file" id="fileu" style="display:none" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)" />
  <button ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the `cordova-plugin-file` and `cordova-plugin-filepath.` You can then use

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( filePath, function (fileEntry) 
{
console.log('got a file entry');
  fileEntry.file(function (file) {
    console.log('created file');
    console.log(file.localURL);
  })
}, function (e) {
  console.log('Error resolving fs url', e);
});
```

`filePath` is the variable I get from cordova when taking a picture or choosing one from the gallery and this resolves the real path that is needed for uploads. You can also use

```
window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(filePath, function(path) { 
// stuff
}, function (e) {
          console.log('Error resolving fs url', e);
        });
```

But for me the first one worked better over different versions of android,ios etc.
After a lot of trial and error I found that for iOS sometimes you need to put `file://` in front of `filePath` or it cannot resolve the path correctly.

Hope I helped you.

Comment: I am not using cordovaCamera plugin. I am simply using <input type="file">. How am i suppose to get filePath again?

Comment: `angular.element(document).find('input')[0].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                    var theFile = e.target.files[0];`
Does this help to get the `filePath`?